# Violation of law of conservation of linear momentum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, momentum, conservation-laws, free-body-diagram

A bike is moving with some velocity.There is some frictional force between the wheels of bike and ground.Now you apply brakes and the bike stops after some time.Brakes apply a force say F on wheels which slows down rotation of wheels,and finally wheels stop rotating.According to newtons 3rd law,wheels will also exert a force of equal magnitude on brakes (in the opposite direction of the force F).Thus,this reaction force on brakes gives momentum to bike which is equal in magnitude to the loss of momentum due to slowing down rotation of wheels. Thus,momentum is conserved so bike would not lose its velocity but rotation of wheels is slowing down continuously.In that case,to obey the law of conservation of momentum, the bike would start sliding and sliding will be opposed by frictional force(between the wheels of bike and ground).This frictional force is the reason of losing momentum.My question is- am i right? All suggestions are welcome,

Comment: If there is no friction between the wheels and the ground, then applying the brakes will have no effect whatsoever on the speed of the bike. (Of course, in reality, if there was no friction between the wheels and the ground, it would not be possible to balance the bike in the first place.)

Comment: The brakes don't oppose the motion of the bike, they only oppose the rotation of the wheels.  It's the friction between wheels and the ground that oppose the motion of the bike.

Comment: The whole concept is wrong . The bike will be sliding if there is no friction. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HDBQZbwG_k0 .

Comment: take somethin simpler, a box sliding on ice. Nothing one can do inside the box will stop it from sliding and keeping momentum conservation.

Comment: @annav, if there is some friction then ?

Comment: The fricton takes up the momentum conservation during breaking, in the way heat is distributed. on the wheels and on the ground. Heat is photons and they carry momentum (classically also radiation which is given off heat caries momentum)

Comment: @annav,is the edited question right?

Comment: @SolomonSlow,is the edited question right?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the bike was at a velocity v. Even if the wheels stop rotating i dont think the bike is going to stop. It can just continue sliding at velocity v as there is no friction. (Its like driving bike on ice and pressing break...it won't stop moving) As a result, momentum doesn't change. 
I think this argument makes sense, any better suggestions or corrections are welcome.

Comment: ,is the edited question right?